# Relative duality for finite holomorphic map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a finite, surjective holomorphic map of complex manifolds. Is there an isomorphism $$
(f_*\mathscr{O}_X)^\vee\cong f_*\omega_X \otimes \omega_Y^*?
$$($\omega_X$ is the canonical sheaf on $X$). In the algebraic case, this can be obtained by the relative duality for finite flat morphism: $ \omega_f=f^!\mathscr{O}_Y\cong \omega_{X/Y}$. But the proof is not direct and cannot be carried into the analytic case. If this holds generally, I think there should be a direct explanation. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Sorry, what is $\pi_*$? Is there any reason that these pushforwards are not derived?

Comment: @Z.M It’s $f_*$. I don’t know any derived pushforward.